# WooCommerce webhooks sending an empty body

Tags: php, woocommerce, webhooks

When the webhook fired, I could see in the other end, that the body of the request was empty.
I then enabled WP_DEBUG, shot another API-call and checked the log-files ( WooCommerce >> Status >> Logs >> Log-file for the given day ), and could see that it indeed was empty. So it wasn't data 'falling off the truck' on the way to the destination.

I found where the shot was done in the code, and it looked like this:

```
do_action( 'my_custom_webhook', $order->id, [], $order );
```

So I changed that to:

```
error_log( $order );
do_action( 'my_custom_webhook', $order->id, [], $order );
```

And could see that the `$order` wasn't empty.

**WIERD!**

### Debugging steps taken

**1. Webhooks defined properly**

I spent quite a bit of time, diving down into the webhooks, seeing if it was something there, that was setup incorrectly. Or some legacy-code that had been deprecated.

**2. Error logs**

I dug through the error-logs several time. Assuming that it was some bad code, that encountered an error, before the API-call was sent. But it didn't make any sense, since that most likely would stop the API-call from firing entirely. Hmm!

**3. Webhooks deactivating automatically**

The API I was hitting, also returned and error 500, when the body was empty. So the webhooks deactivated themselves. Whenever I tried to reactivate them, I still got an error (either of these two):

- Error: Delivery URL returned response code: 500
- Error: Delivery URL cannot be reached: cURL error 28: Operation tiemd out after 5001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received.
  I thought for a long time, that that was centralt to the problem.

But I couldn't get the API changed. So there was no good way around this.

I eventually realized, that even though that I got that error, the the webhook was still activated... And worked!

So I simply ignored that error entirely and moved on.

**4. Permissions**

I thought that maybe it was something about permissions, since I would see that I got a `woocommerce_rest_cannot_view`-error.

### System details

- WordPress-version 5.8.1
- WooCommerce-version: 4.9.3
- The site is a custom site, that has been built on Trellis, Bedrock and Sage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was found here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/24533#issuecomment-551148570

Simply delete the webhook(s) and create it/them again with the exact same contents.

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`